# Use replaceUrl in an Angular route to omit redirects from browser history

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routing

Suppose I have these Angular 11 routes:

```typescript
{
  path: 'wizard',
  children: [
    { path: 'step1', component: Step1Component },
    { path: 'step2', component: Step2Component },
    { path: 'step3', component: Step3Component },
    { path: '**', redirectTo: 'step1' },
  ]
}
```

Now if I navigate to `http://localhost:4200/wizard/incorrectpath` I get redirected to `http://localhost:4200/wizard/step1` which is perfect. However, the first, incorrect path does become part of the browser history.

When I use active routing commands I can do:

```typescript
this.router.navigate(['wizard', 'step1'], { replaceUrl: true });
```

This ensures that the original route is replaced in the browser history. This makes sure that if the user uses "Back" they don't land on the route that redirects them "forward" *again*.

**Can you use `replaceUrl` or similar in a `Route` somehow?**

The `Route` interface doesn't seem to have the property. My current workaround is to *not* use `redirectTo` but instead use a complete component that does active routing with `.navigate(...)` but I want to avoid that as it is *far* more verbose.